# css scale image

Tags: css, image, scale

Say I have a picture 1000x1000.

Is there any way to set a background image for a 300x300 table thats zoomed or scaled in on pageload so it shows a specific part of that image at 2000 x 2000 size instead of 1000 x 1000?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [CSS3 background-size Property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp)

But not all browsers supports it yet: http://caniuse.com/#search=background-image%20options

Comment: He can use this polyfill to replace the functionality in older browsers. It seems to work pretty well - http://nooshu.com/jquery-plug-in-scalable-background-image

Comment: is their anyway to make it not blur when it rescales?

Comment: another q, would it matter how big the image is? Does the browser have to load all the image first and then splice off just the bit I need (with backgroundPosition) or does it only grab the splice from the server?

Comment: It will load all the image first. May be situation will change, but for now all browsers download full version of image as I know.